# Laravel, Formulario se envia doble

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Buenos días, estoy empezando con laravel y he creado un sistema de login/registro mediante Auth pero tengo un problema, intento poner el formulario del login y del registro en la misma pagina y al darle a "Logear" se envian tanto los datos del primer formulario como del segundo.

Cuando dejo el formulario vacio y le doy al boton "Entrar" me muestra

> The nombre field is required.
>
> The password field is required.
>
> The nombre field is required.
>
> The password field is required.

```
            {{ $errors->first('nombre') }}
            {{ $errors->first('password') }}

            {{ $errors->first('nombre') }}
            {{ $errors->first('password') }}
            <section class="wPanelUsuario" id="Login">
                <h3>Bienvenido</h3>
                <form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="POST">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Usuario" value="{{ old('nombre') }}"/>
                  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" value="{{ old('password') }}"/>
                  <input type="submit" class="botonPrimario" value="Entrar">
                  <a class="botonSecundario" id="suBoton">Registrarme</a>
                </form>
            </section>

            <section class="wPanelUsuario none" id="Registro">
                <h3>Ya casí...</h3>
                <p class="text-center">¡Estás a un paso de obtener funciones exclusivas para usuarios registrados!</p>
                <form action="{{ route('register') }}" method="POST">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Usuario" value="{{ old('nombre') }}" required/>
                  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" value="{{ old('email') }}" required/>
                  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" value="{{ old('password') }}" required/>
                  <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Repite tu contraseña" value="{{ old('password2') }}" required/>
                  <input type="submit" class="botonPrimario" value="Registrarme">
                  <a class="botonSecundario" id="loginBoton">Iniciar sesión</a>
                </form>
            </section>
```

El problema esque tengo dos input llamado con el mismo nombre ("nombre","password"). He probado a cambiar el nombre de los input a uno de los formularios pero el problema esta en que automaticamente utiliza ese nombre para insertar los datos en la base de dato y por lo cual, me da error tambien.

---

Controlador:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'nombre' => 'required|string|unique:Usuarios',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:Usuarios',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|string|min:6|same:password',
    ]);
}
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'nombre' => $data['nombre'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Al poner email1 ya me salta el siguiente error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email1' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `Usuarios` where `email1` = ejemplo@ejemplo.com)

Comment: No veo ningún botón que se llame "Logear".

Comment: @Shaz Si, <input type="submit" class="botonPrimario" value="Entrar">

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sencilla de solucionar dicho problema es efectivamente renombrar dichos campos de forma temporal, pero en el controlador regresarlos a la forma que desea Laravel. Es como hacer una especie de mapeo de los mismos, solo para la validación:

```
        <section class="wPanelUsuario" id="Login">
            <h3>Bienvenido</h3>
            <form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="POST">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Usuario" value="{{ old('nombre') }}"/>
              <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" value="{{ old('password') }}"/>
              <input type="submit" class="botonPrimario" value="Entrar">
              <a class="botonSecundario" id="suBoton">Registrarme</a>
            </form>
        </section>

        <section class="wPanelUsuario none" id="Registro">
            <h3>Ya casí...</h3>
            <p class="text-center">¡Estás a un paso de obtener funciones exclusivas para usuarios registrados!</p>
            <form action="{{ route('register') }}" method="POST">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
              <input type="text" name="nombre2" placeholder="Usuario" value="{{ old('nombre2') }}" required/>
              <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="Correo electrónico" value="{{ old('correo') }}" required/>
              <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña" value="{{ old('contrasena') }}" required/>
              <input type="password" name="contrasena_confirmation" placeholder="Repite tu contraseña" value="{{ old('contrasena_confirmation') }}" required/>
              <input type="submit" class="botonPrimario" value="Registrarme">
              <a class="botonSecundario" id="loginBoton">Iniciar sesión</a>
            </form>
        </section>
```

Asumo que realizas la validación en el Request:

Validación del formulario de registro:

```
class RequestCrearUsuario extends Request
{

    // ...


    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'nombre2'       => 'required|max:255',
            'correo'        => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
            'contrasena'    => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ];
     }
```

En el método del controlador que recibe los datos del registro:

```
public function register(RequestCrearUsuario $request)
{
    $request['nombre'] = $request['nombre2'];
    $request['password'] = $request['contrasena'];
    unset($request['nombre2']);
    unset($request['contrasena']);

    // ....

}
```

**EDICIÓN**

Otra opción puede ser agregar un valor a la sesión en algún punto del proceso que identifique de donde viene la solicitud (del formulario de login o de registro):

Si la solicitud viene del formulario de registro:

```
$request->session()->flash('formulario', 'registro');
```

O del de login:

```
$request->session()->flash('formulario', 'login');
```

En la vista sería algo así:

```
    @if(Session::get('formulario') == 'login')
        {{ $errors->first('nombre') }}
        {{ $errors->first('password') }}
    @endif

    @if(Session::get('formulario') == 'registro')
        {{ $errors->first('nombre') }}
        {{ $errors->first('password') }
    @endif
```

Comment: Si..., es una opción. Pero me temo que debería de tener una solución mas facil y sencilla

Comment: Cómo te imaginas esa solución más fácil?

Comment: No se puede identificar a cada formulario con un id y mostrar los errores de ese formulario(id)?

Comment: Sería jugar con la sesión, voy a editar la respuesta para mostrar una idea.

Comment: ¿Pudiste implementar alguno de los métodos?

Answer (score 0):

Te estás complicando, para que duplicas dos veces más la comprobación de errores? Yo lo dejaría así, como cada formulario va a una acción independiente y tiene los mismos "name=", al hacer submit estas comprobando cada formulario por separado. Solo necesitas esas dos lineas para ambos formularios.

```
{{ $errors->first('nombre') }}
{{ $errors->first('password') }}

<section class="wPanelUsuario" id="Login">
    <h3>Bienvenido</h3>
    <form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="POST">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Usuario" value="{{ old('nombre') }}"/>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" value="{{ old('password') }}"/>
      <input type="submit" class="botonPrimario" value="Entrar">
      <a class="botonSecundario" id="suBoton">Registrarme</a>
    </form>
</section>

<section class="wPanelUsuario none" id="Registro">
    <h3>Ya casí...</h3>
    <p class="text-center">¡Estás a un paso de obtener funciones exclusivas para usuarios registrados!</p>
    <form action="{{ route('register') }}" method="POST">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Usuario" value="{{ old('nombre') }}" required/>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" value="{{ old('email') }}" required/>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" value="{{ old('password') }}" required/>
      <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Repite tu contraseña" value="{{ old('password2') }}" required/>
      <input type="submit" class="botonPrimario" value="Registrarme">
      <a class="botonSecundario" id="loginBoton">Iniciar sesión</a>
    </form>
</section>
```